# Python scraping: 403 and 503 Errors

Tags: python, web-crawler, http-error

I am trying to crawl some public information(apple app's info) on a website.

This website requires log-in in order to perform actions such as "search app/developer". Although there are many website provide similar information, but I consider this particular website provides the most complete and detailed info for each app.

I, as a valid user, am able to perform the task.

However, when I try to access the info via python code, I have the encountered 403 Error when sending POST request, and 504 Error when sending Get request.

I have tried using

1. real userAgent header
2. fake-useragent" package
3. FancyOpener[/sth like that, shown depreciated for python 3.4]
4. HttpAuthM..[/sth like that, for authentication, still doesn't work]

I guess the website is highly against automate access, but the detailed info there is highly useful. Is there any way I could workaround this issue?

Thanks!!

I tried this header:

```
ua = {#'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +Googlebot - Webmaster Tools Help)',  
      'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.124 Safari/537.36',  
      'Connection':'Keep-Alive',  
      'Accept-Language':'zh-CN,zh;q=0.8',  
      'Accept-Encoding':'gzip,deflate,sdch',  
      'Accept':'*/*',  
      'Accept-Charset':'GBK,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',  
      'Cache-Control':'max-age=0'  
      }
```

[503 Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUcfv.jpg)

[403 Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zTDM.jpg)

```
------------------------------------------------ HTTPError   
Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-43-421b27c5194e> in <module>()
     68 data= data.encode('utf-8')
     69 request = urq.Request(url, data, headers = ua)
---> 70 response = urq.urlopen(request)
     71 the_page = response.read()
     72 print(the_page)

c:\python34\lib\urllib\request.py in urlopen(url, data, timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
    159     else:
    160         opener = _opener
--> 161     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    162 
    163 def install_opener(opener):

c:\python34\lib\urllib\request.py in open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    468         for processor in self.process_response.get(protocol, []):
    469             meth = getattr(processor, meth_name)
--> 470             response = meth(req, response)
    471 
    472         return response

c:\python34\lib\urllib\request.py in http_response(self, request, response)
    578         if not (200 <= code < 300):
    579             response = self.parent.error(
--> 580                 'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
    581 
    582         return response

c:\python34\lib\urllib\request.py in error(self, proto, *args)
    506         if http_err:
    507             args = (dict, 'default', 'http_error_default') + orig_args
--> 508             return self._call_chain(*args)
    509 
    510 # XXX probably also want an abstract factory that knows when it makes

c:\python34\lib\urllib\request.py in _call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
    440         for handler in handlers:
    441             func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
--> 442             result = func(*args)
    443             if result is not None:
    444                 return result

c:\python34\lib\urllib\request.py in http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs)
    586 class HTTPDefaultErrorHandler(BaseHandler):
    587     def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
--> 588         raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    589 
    590 class HTTPRedirectHandler(BaseHandler):

HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: FORBIDDEN
----------------------------------------------
```

The below result I obtained by using "Advanced REST client", which is a chrome extension to send request. Notice how on a page that doesn't require log in, the code is 200; the other one was 403 at login page.See link in comment below

[access success][3]

[access fail][4]

Answer (score 0):

plain python requests package is enough, you shouldn't need other packages.

I'm sure your problem is just you're not perfectly emulating a browser request.
On Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox you should be able to see requests headers from a developer panel.

Be sure you always use the **same** session object.

Be sure not to forget to set proper headers:

- User-Agent
- Accept
- Accept-Language
- Accept-Encoding
- **Referer**  (url of previous GET request)
- Connection (keep-alive)
- **Host** ( abc.website.com )

.

```
session.headers = {
    'User-Agent' : 'real one',
    ...
}
```

Be sure to respect redirects:

```
session.get(url, allow_redirects=True, timeout=x_secs)
```

In post requests be sure you send all the required fields, there may be some hidden ones (like the csfr token).

Comment: Hi @nonsensei, is it okay for me to ask for a sample of properly emulated request and session? I have tried this header before but still failed. could you point to me what's the problem please?

Comment: Sorry please see edited post. I tried posted in comment but too hard to read

Comment: there may be hidden fields or missing headers, could you post your code and a link to a non-working page?.

You forgot the Host header

Comment: [3]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/zD82L.jpg
  [4]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/HLFa7.jpg

The website is: www.appannie.com

finger cross they won't block me when they see this post lol

Comment: https://www.appannie.com/search/?q=Wombat+Apps+LLC+&market     This is the link I tried to reach. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I would also like to suggest, as an alternative (I use it a lot for my scrapers requiring login) robobrowser. Give it a shot

Comment: @KeepLearning it seems they provide API to access their database. By the way I couldn't verify the email used to register so many links returns FORBIDDEN for me. I think ***Host*** should be plain "www.appannie.com" without "https" prefix

Comment: @KeepLearning I saw the login is a post request with a ***csfr token*** so you must include this field in the form data also!